# Process with an id of "xxxx" is not running in Visual Studio(included 2013 to 2017~ version)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

I am not able to run any application from Visual Studio 2013, It throws Process with an id of "xxxx" is not running message. I have used telerik also. I tried all solutions from internet (except reinstall visual studio), nothing helped me, Please help, Thank you.

Ps: WebForm base.

Comment: I see the same issue in C++ when I stop the debugger and want to debug again. I which Microsoft would fix this issue. I don't see the same problem in other similar test frameworks.

Answer (score 22):

1. Open Visual Studio as an administrator
2. Right-click your project and click on `Unload Project`
3. Again, right-click your project and click on `Edit PROJECT_NAME.csproj`
4. Find the code below and delete it

   ```
   <DevelopmentServerPort>63366</DevelopmentServerPort>
   <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
   <IISUrl>http://localhost:63366/</IISUrl>
   ```
5. Save and close the file
6. Right-click your project and reload it
7. See if it's working

Comment: I was about to lose my mind until I stumbled upon your answer. Guys, do any of you have any logical explanation of why this was happening? I was working on the damn thing just yesterday. Today, I get this "process with an id of xxx is not running"!!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and the solution was pretty simple.

1. close your solution.
2. reopen the solution as an admin.
3. rebuild it.
4. try now.

You may need to restart your machine.
Don't delete any of the csproj  file settings.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem and I found a great way to cope this problem as following

> 1.Open your project file:
>   *.csproj
>   2.Try to find the lines shown below (by finding "DevelopmentServerPort" in your project file).
>
> ```
>  <DevelopmentServerPort>62140</DevelopmentServerPort>    
>  <DevelopmentServerVPath></DevelopmentServerVPath>    
>  <IISUrl>http://localhost:62116/</IISUrl>
> ```
>
> 3.When found, delete the below tags from your project file:
>
> 4.Save and close the file. If you had your project opened, you may be prompted to reload the project.

full reference [URL](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1029540/Solved-Process-With-An-Id-Of-Is-Not-Running)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and solutions found online did not help.  Here is what worked for me:

When the problem occurs...

1. Change the startup project to another project in your solution.
2. Run that project once.
3. Change the startup project to the original project.

In my case, an error popped because the chosen port was already used.  This means, you have to select a new port.  For some reason, the chosen port is sometimes taken and sometimes free.

To select a new port, right click on your projet then `Properties`.  In the `Web` tab, change the port in the `Project URL` filed.

You should avoid using a port from 0 to 1024. Select a funky number like: 12321 or 23432 which is high enough an easy to remember.

Answer (score 1):

For me, using Visual Studio 2017, the tags mentioned in ali abid's answer were located in the csproj.user file.

However removing these tags did no solve my problem. For me, I had set up a virtual directory in the project properties with a low (9500) port number. I think some other process decided to use that port and was blocking my IIS Express from starting.

The solution was to edit the project properties, update Web --> Project Url to use a new port, and create a virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

Only unloading and reloading the startup project fixed this, I needed no other steps actually.

Comment: Just closing the solution and opening it does not help. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The only think that worked for me was restartying Visual Studio completely.

I tried in vain to kill all suspended vstest.executionengine.exe processes and the vstest.discoiveryengine.exe using Process Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the first error and that didn't help me. However What did work for me was to delete the hidden ".vs" folder which is at the solution root. You'll have to close down visual studio, delete the folder, reopen the solution and Visual Studio will create a new "correct" instance of the folder.

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40994480/5292302) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplica‌​te-answer-to-several-questions)

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue and explore project directory and remove this .vs hidden folder. If you cannot see this folder, go to your folder option, show all files and then remove this folder.
Close project and then clean and build then enter F5.
[image]