# @@Process with an id (####) of is not running in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#

I have tried the different solutions below but still facing the same issue can you please help on this how can we resolve it.

- By removing the .vs folder with the respective project.
- By unloading the project and editing removing the below lines of code and saving project changes like below.
- By Following with the iisreset command
- Repair and reinstall visual studio and IIS express
- By setting control panel >> system >> advanced settings >> Environment variables.

I have tried all solutions but still getting the same issue as below.

I have gone through some references followed below. but still, the issue is not fixe

[Process with an ID #### is not running in visual studio professional 2013 update 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424902/process-with-an-id-is-not-running-in-visual-studio-professional-2013-update)

[Visual studio 2017 process with an id of is not running error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55880502/visual-studio-2017-process-with-an-id-of-is-not-running-error)

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1029540/Solved-Process-With-An-Id-Of-Is-Not-Running

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem in VS 2022. My solution was:

- open the property of the csproj,
- set build -> target plattform from "Any CPU" to "x86"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has really worked for me always.

1. Remove the .vs folder with the respective project.
2. Unload the project.
3. Right-click your project and click on 'Edit PROJECT_NAME.csproj'
4. Find this code and delete it.

`<DevelopmentServerPort>53354</DevelopmentServerPort>`
`<DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>`
`<IISUrl>http://localhost:53354/</IISUrl>`

5. Save and close the file .csproj
6. Right-click your project and reload it.
7. Rebuild the project and Clean.

Done!!!